# SqlParser not working for random word in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Here is the function I am passing to my command to validate the string to be a valid Sql query.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;
using ParseError = Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError;

namespace QueryStore.Application.Utils;

internal static class SqlParser
{
    internal static List<string>? Parse(string sql)
    {
        var parser = new TSql100Parser(false);
        parser.Parse(new StringReader(sql), out IList<ParseError> errors);
        return errors is not { Count: > 0 } ? null : errors.Select(error => error.Message).ToList();
    }
    
    internal static bool BeValidSqlQuery(string content)
    {
        var result = SqlParser.Parse(content);
        return result is null;
    }

}
```

This input gives error: `"Select From XYZ"` 
Here are some input string it accepts

```
"sdcsdcsdcsdcsjnjkc"
"csdcsdc sdcsdcsdc"
```

How can i avoid this to happen. Are there any other existing functions i can use or some other library?

Comment: You probably want [ParseStatementList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser.parsestatementlist?view=sql-transactsql-161).

Comment: Yes this method works correctly. Thank you for taking time and answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on this. My concern is that what Parse does.

The Parse method does validate the input, however it deals with more than sql statement. When you give the string you mentioned, it is recognized as identifier, so the string will be returned as TSqlFragment. That’s why there is no error.

[image]

When you input random words like 123 and abc, it will also return error not because it is incorrect sql ,but because it cannot be recognized as identifier correctly.

[image]

To validate the sql with Parse, you need to give further validation such as checking if it inherits from TSqlStatement. You can write the text and type of child of scriptTokenStream to check the process of validation.

```
var sqlresult = parser.Parse(new StringReader(sql), out IList<ParseError> errors);
    foreach (var child in sqlresult.ScriptTokenStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", child.Text, child.TokenType);
    }
```

ParseStatementList method is the simple and correct way to validate only the sql. It will return object of StatementList, of which each sentence inherits from TSqlStatement .

[image]

[image]